# How to send ERC20 tokens from contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, contract-debugging

I've created an escrow contract, and I want the 'deposit' to be in my own ERC20 token so I've sent the ERC20 tokens to the contract address. The contract can be seen below:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
 contract Escrow {

 address public challenger;
 address public participant;
 address public arbiter;

 function Escrow(address _participant, address _arbiter) {
   challenger = msg.sender;
   participant = _participant;
   arbiter = _arbiter;
 }

 function payoutToParticipant() {
   if(msg.sender == challenger || msg.sender == arbiter) {
     participant.send(this.balance);
   }
 }

 function refundToChallenger() {
   if(msg.sender == challenger || msg.sender == arbiter) {
     challenger.send(this.balance);
   }
 }

 function getBalance() constant returns (uint) {
   return this.balance;
 }

}
```

After sending the tokens to the address, do I now just call payoutToParticipant() from the challenger or the arbiter to send the tokens? Or will it just send the 0 ETH? Additionally, why does the contract not have to sign the transaction as a user would?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.send()` function sends Ethereum from contract balance, not tokens. So you need to call token `transfer` function.

Also I advise you to always you `send()` function within `require()` because `send()` doesn't throw exception and your debug process could be harder.

> Additionally, why does the contract not have to sign the transaction
>   as a user would?

Because contract can't execute it's own functions by itself. All functions can be triggered only when real user send signed transaction with correct `data` field (contains information about calling function and arguments) to Ethereum network.

Comment: Ok great thanks, so I need to change the code from 'challenger.send(this.balance);' to calling transfer on the contract. Ok that makes some sense! Thanks :)